# Shiny Application to fetch twitter search results and show last 5 tweets and word cloud as output

Tags: r, twitter, download, shiny, word-cloud

I am trying to create a Shiny application wherein the user inputs a text string to search on twitter along with the option to choose the number of tweets to fetch, the language of the tweets and the ability to download the tweets in a csv file. I want the output to be a table of the last 5 tweets and a word cloud of the tweets fetched. I was able to get the tweets, display the last 5 tweets but I am not able to download the tweets and get the correct word cloud output using the following code:

```
library(shiny)
library(twitteR)


shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(
  headerPanel("Tweets hunter"),

  sidebarPanel(textInput("term", "Enter a term", ""),
  sliderInput("cant", "Select a number of tweets",min=5,max=1500, value = 5),
  radioButtons("lang", "Select the language", c(
    "English"="en",
    "Spanish"="es",
    "Dutch"="nl")),
  submitButton(text = "Run"),

  downloadButton("download", "Download File")),


  mainPanel(
    h4("Last 5 tweets"),
    tableOutput("table"),
    plotOutput("wordcl"))
))

library(shiny)
library(twitteR)
library(wordcloud)
library(tm)

consumerKey = "My Key"   
consumerSecret = "My Secret"
accessToken = "My Token"
accessSecret = "My Secret"
my_oauth <- setup_twitter_oauth(consumer_key = consumerKey, consumer_secret = consumerSecret,
                                access_token = accessToken, access_secret = accessSecret)



shinyServer(function(input,output){

  rawData <- (function(){
    tweets <- searchTwitter(input$term, n=input$cant,lang=input$lang)
    twListToDF(tweets)
  })

  output$table <- renderTable(function(){
    head(rawData()[1],n=5)
  })

output$wordcl <- renderPlot(function(){
  tw.text <- enc2native(rawData()$text)
  tw.text <- tolower(tw.text)
  tw.text <- removeWords(tw.text,c(stopwords(input$lang),"rt"))
tw.text <- removePunctuation(tw.text, TRUE)
tw.text <- unlist(strsplit(tw.text,""))

word <- sort(table(tw.text),TRUE)
wordc <- head(word,n=15)



wordcloud(names(wordc),wordc,random.color = TRUE,colors = rainbow(10),scale = c(15,2))
  })

output$download <- downloadHandler(filename = function() {paste(input$term, '.csv', sep='')},
                                   content = function(file){
                                     write.csv(rawData(), file)
                                   }
)


})
```

For the above code, I am getting the following output:

[image: Output]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: the individual characters in the wordcloud are the result your `strsplit(tw.text,"")`. You are missing a space to split the sentences into words: `strsplit(tw.text," ")`.

Comment: Solved. Thanks so much Dave.